# Diferença entre Executar App (Run App) e Aplicar alterações (Apply changes)

Tags: android-studio

Na barra de ferramentas do Android Studio, temos 2 botões:

- Executar App (Run App)
- Aplicar alterações (Apply changes)

[image: Botões]

Qual a diferença entre eles ? E quando usar um ou outro ?

---

***Update***

A IDE identifica a necessidade de usar o "Run App" ? Ou seja, quando é feita alguma alteração que o "Apply changes" não irá aplicar, somente o botão "Run App" ficará ativo ?

Comment: Downvoter, me diga seu problema com a pergunta para que eu possa melhorá-la " ;]

Answer (score 4):

**Apply Changes:** Envia somente a parte alterada do código, e não cria um novo `APK` e em alguns casos reinicia alguma `activity`.

**Run App:** Neste caso ele reinicia a aplicação, atualiza o `manifest`, e envia outro `APK`.

*Fonte:* [run app vs apply changes android studio 2.3](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html?hl=pt-br)

**Update**

**Run App**

> Para compilar e executar seu aplicativo, clique em Run . O Android
>   Studio compila seu aplicativo com o Gradle, solicita que você
>   selecione um destino de implantação (um emulador ou dispositivo
>   conectado) e implanta seu aplicativo nele. Você pode personalizar
>   alguns desses comportamento padrão, como selecionar um destino de
>   implantação automático, ao alterar a configuração de execução.

**Apply Changes**

> Após implantar um aplicativo, um pequeno ícone de raio amarelo será
>   exibido no botão Run (ou no botão Debug ), indicando que o Instant Run
>   está pronto para enviar atualizações na próxima vez que você clicar no
>   botão. Em vez de compilar um novo APK, ele envia apenas essas novas
>   alterações e, em alguns casos, o aplicativo sequer precisa ser
>   reiniciado e imediatamente mostra o efeito das alterações de código.

Mais informações do próprio site da IDE: [Compilar e executar seu aplicativo](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html?hl=pt-br)

O site em inglês esta mais atualizado: [Build and Run Your App](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#instant-run)

Comment: Em vista o "Run App" seria de último caso. Ainda fico na dúvida se ele seria para uma alteração do Gradle, ou algo mais específico, porém, pensando melhor agora com esse pedaço da sua resposta `" indicando que o Instant Run está pronto para enviar atualizações na próxima vez que você clicar no botão"`, me veio a dúvida: Quando faço uma alteração, em que preciso recompilar, reinstalar, o app, ou seja, dar um "Run App", o botão "Apply changes" ficaria bloqueado.